# Null Conditional in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, null-conditional-operator

[C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) and other languages have null-conditionals usually `?.`

```
A?.B?.Do($C);
```

Will not error out when A or B are null.
How do I achieve something similar in powershell, what's a nicer way to do:

```
if ($A) {
  if ($B) {
    $A.B.Do($C);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PowerShell doesn't have the null-conditional operator, but it silently ignores *property* references on null-value expressions, so you can just "skip" to the method call at the end of the chain:

```
if($null -ne $A.B){
  $A.B.Do($C)
}
```

Works at any depth:

```
if($null -ne ($target = $A.B.C.D.E)){
    $target.Do($C)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Powershell 7 Preview 5 has operators that deal with nulls. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-7-preview-5/

```
$a = $null

$a ?? 'is null' # return $a or string if null
is null

$a ??= 'no longer null'  # assign if null

$a ?? 'is null'
no longer null
```

EDIT:  Powershell 7 Preview 6 piles on more new operators:  https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-7-preview-6/.  Since variable names can have a '?' in the name, you have to surround the variable name with curly braces:

```
${A}?.${B}?.Do($C)
```

Comment: `.?` and `??` are _not the same_

Comment: Indeed: While related to the _null-conditional [member-access] operator_ the question is about, the features you mention are _null-coalescing_ and _null[-conditional] assignment_.

Answer (score 7):

As [Mathias R. Jessen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58560876/45375) points out, **PowerShell *by default* has null-conditional access behavior (null-soaking) with respect to *property access***<sup>[1]</sup>; e.g., `$noSuchVar.Prop` quietly returns `$null`

<sup>[js2010's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58561050/45375) shows the related ***null-coalescing* operator (`??`) / *null-conditional-assignment* operators (`??=`)**, which are **available in PowerShell [Core] v 7.1+**</sup>

However, **up to PowerShell 7.0**:

- There is ***no* way to null-conditionally ignore *method* calls**: `$noSuchVar.Foo()` always fails.
- Similarly, there's ***no* way to null-conditionally ignore (array) *indexing***: `$noSuchVar[0]` always fails.
- If you opt into more rigorous behavior with `Set-StrictMode`, even the property-access null-soaking is no longer an option: with `Set-StrictMode -Version 1` or higher, `$noSuchVar.Prop` results in an error.

In **PowerShell [Core] 7.1+**, ***null-conditional (null-soaking)* operators *are* available**:

The new operators:

- have the **same form as in C# *in principle***: **`?.`** and **`?[...]`**
- but - **as of v7.1** - *require **enclosing the variable name in `{...}`***

That is, **you currently cannot use just `$noSuchVar?.Foo()`, `$A?.B`, or `$A?[1]`, you have to use

`${noSuchVar}?.Foo()`, `${A}?.B`, or `${A}?[1]`**

The reason for this cumbersome syntax is that there are *backward-compatibility concerns*, because `?` is a legitimate character in variable names, so hypothetical existing code such as `$var? = @{ one = 1}; $var?.one` could break without using the `{...}` to disambiguate the variable name; in practice, such use is [vanishingly rare](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11379#issuecomment-689858916).

**If you think that not encumbering the new syntax is more important than potentially breaking scripts with variable names ending in `?`, make your voice heard at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14025)**.

---

<sup>[1] PowerShell's default behavior even offers *existence*-conditional property access; e.g., `$someObject.NoSuchProp` quietly returns `$null`.</sup>